# border-radius vs -moz-border-radius

Tags: css

This just came to my mind while adding a border radius to my `<div>`. Since the `border-radius` CSS property works fine in Mozilla, why do we need `-moz-border-radius`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For older versions of Firefox, namely Firefox 3.6 and earlier.

Comment: you were faster just for 30 seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a (brief) history of using vendor-specific prefixes like this that enable the code to be read more easily by earlier browsers. In the beginning of HTML5/CSS3 support, each browser handled elements differently, so border-radius would be like:

```
.rectangle {
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -o-border-radius:5px;
 border-radius:5px;
```

}

Nowadays, many modern browsers accept styling like 'border-radius' (for example, the latest Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE9), so as minitech referred to earlier, these stylings are now used to support older versions of modern browsers.

Comment: I don't mean that they are read more easily by the new browsers, I just mean that when browsers were released they only really accepted the vendor prefixes, so by saying "read more easily" I mean that they could read them. Now these are needed only by older version modern browsers who don't accept the standard.